# Correct way to use Poly1305 with ChaCha20?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

I'm trying to use `ChaCha20-Poly1305` cipher from the `cryptography` module,
but there is only `ChaCha20` cipher and `Poly1305` MAC available.
This is the way I tried to combine them at first:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.poly1305 import Poly1305
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import (
    Cipher,
    algorithms as algo,
)
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend as defb


class ChaCha20Poly1305:
    def __init__(self, locking, key, nonce):
        self._locking = locking
        # only accepts 16 bytes nonce
        cipher = Cipher(algo.ChaCha20(key, nonce), None, defb())
        if locking:
            self._cipher = cipher.encryptor()
        else:
            self._cipher = cipher.decryptor()
        self._auth = Poly1305(key)
        self._auth.update(nonce)

    def update(self, data):
        ctxt = self._cipher.update(data)
        self._auth.update(ctxt)
        return ctxt

    def finalize(self, tag=None):
        if not self._locking
            if tag is None:
                raise ValueError('tag required')
            self._auth.verify(tag)

    def calculate_tag(self):
        return self._auth.calculate_tag()
```

Is this the correct way to use this cipher with Poly1305?

Edit: Although `cryptography` provides [`ChaCha20Poly1305`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/aead/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead.ChaCha20Poly1305),
it does **NOT** support encrypting data continuously.
It simply takes a piece of data, encrypts it and returns the ciphertext
with appended MAC. And that is not what I want.

Comment: _Cryptography_ directly provides [`ChaCha20Poly1305`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/aead/).

Comment: @Topaco The `ChaCha20Poly1305` provided by it does not support continuous data encryption/decryption. It simply takes a piece of data and spits encrypted data with appended MAC, and that is not what I want. I'll put this info in my question.

Comment: cryptography does not provide an incremental API for chacha20poly1305 because it strongly encourages users to perform operations on unauthenticated data (since you cannot know whether what you've decrypted is safe or not until every byte is processed and the MAC tag is checked). If you want to do things incrementally I strongly suggest slicing your data into chunks and processing each chunk as a separate chachapoly invocation. This framing gives you security with bounded memory sizes.

Comment: @PaulKehrer but then why would they give a `Poly1305` MAC, if what you said is true? And my question was to know the corret way to use the MAC and cipher.

Comment: A MAC can only be validated after all the plaintext it protects is processed. So if you have a 64GB file and you decrypt it incrementally you can decrypt 64GB - 1 byte and you still won't know if any of it is valid until the final byte is processed and you do the MAC comparison.

Comment: Streaming authenticated encryption / decryption with the _Cryptography_ implementations `ChaCha20` and `Poly1305`, analogous to the _PyCryptodome_ implementation `ChaCha20_Poly1305`, is possible (although perhaps not the most reliable design, s. the comments). Your code essentially does this already. What is still missing to make it work _properly_ is the derivation of the `Poly1305` key, the proper handling of the nonce, the formatting of the data before generating the tag and the processing of the additional authenticated data (AAD).

Comment: @Topaco Can you please explain the point: formatting of data before generating the tag?

Comment: Before the tag is generated, AAD (if present) and ciphertext are Zero padded and the length of the AAD and the ciphertext are appended to the end each as an 8 byte integer in little endian byte order. This is described in full detail in RFC 7539, sec 2.8, see also my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to implement a *streaming authenticated encryption / decryption* with the *Cryptography* implementations `ChaCha20` and `Poly1305` analogous to the *PyCryptodome* implementation `ChaCha20_Poly1305`. The posted code already does this essentially, whereby the following points are missing or buggy:

- The *cryptography* implementation `ChaCha20` expects the complete 16 bytes IV, i.e. nonce (12 bytes) and counter (4 bytes), in little endian format, s. [RFC 7539 sec 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.3).
- The counter value `0` is used to generate the `Poly1305` key, the counter values from and including `1` for encryption, s. [RFC 7539 sec 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.4) and [sec 2.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.6).
- The `Poly1305` key does not simply correspond to the encryption key, but must be derived from this and the nonce with the counter `0`, s. [RFC 7539 sec 2.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.6).
- Apart from the derivation of the `Poly1305` key, the nonce is not further involved in the calculation of the tag.
- The *additional authenticated data* (AAD) must be taken into account, s. [RFC 7539 sec 2.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.8).
- Before the tag is calculated, the data (AAD, if present, and ciphertext) are formatted in a defined way, using Zero padding for AAD and ciphertext and appending the lengths of AAD and ciphertext each as an 8 byte integer in little endian byte order, s. [RFC 7539 sec 2.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.8).

The following code takes these points into account, should illustrate the fundamentals and must / can be adapted to individual needs:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend as defb
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.poly1305 import Poly1305
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import algorithms as algo

class ChaCha20Poly1305:
    def __init__(self, encrypt, key, nonce):
        self._encrypt = encrypt
        self._dataLength = 0;
        self._aadLength = 0;
        self._nonceCounter = (0).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little') + nonce      # Create 16 bytes IV for Poly1305 key derivation
        self._nonceEncrypt = (1).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little') + nonce      # Create 16 bytes IV for encryption / decryption
        
        cipher = Cipher(algo.ChaCha20(key, self._nonceEncrypt), None, defb())
        if encrypt:
            self._cipher = cipher.encryptor()
        else:
            self._cipher = cipher.decryptor()
        
        polyKey = self.__getPolyKey(key)                                      # Get Poly1305 key 
        self._auth = Poly1305(polyKey)
    
    # Add AAD and zero pad if nnecessary (optional, may only be called once and before first 'update' call)    
    def updateAAD(self, aad):
        self._auth.update(aad)
        self._aadLength = len(aad)
        self._auth.update(self.__getZeroBytes(self._aadLength))

    # Add ciphertext / plaintext for encryption / decryption and actualize tag
    def update(self, data):
        ctxt = self._cipher.update(data)
        self._dataLength += len(ctxt)
        if self._encrypt:   
            self._auth.update(ctxt)
        else:
            self._auth.update(data)
        return ctxt

    # Complete padding and verify tag (only decryption)
    def verify_tag(self, tag=None):
        if not self._encrypt:
            self.__pad()
            if tag is None:
                raise ValueError('tag required')
            self._auth.verify(tag)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Tag verification only during decryption')

    # Complete padding and calculate tag (only encryption)
    def calculate_tag(self):
        if self._encrypt:
            self.__pad()
            return self._auth.finalize()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Tag calculation only during encryption')
        
    # Complete formatting: zero pad ciphertext, append AAD and ciphertext lengths
    def __pad(self):
        self._auth.update(self.__getZeroBytes(self._dataLength))
        self._auth.update(self._aadLength.to_bytes(8, byteorder='little'))
        self._auth.update(self._dataLength.to_bytes(8, byteorder='little'))

    # Zero pad data (AAD or ciphertext)
    def __getZeroBytes(self, len):
        spareBytes = len % 16
        if (spareBytes != 0):
            length = 16 - spareBytes
            return bytes([0]) * length
        return b''

    # Derive Poly1305 key
    def __getPolyKey(self, key):
        cipher = Cipher(algo.ChaCha20(key, self._nonceCounter), None, defb())
        cipher = cipher.encryptor()
        key = cipher.update(b"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
        return key
```

The implementation satisfies the test vector from [RFC 7539, sec 2.8.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.8.2):

```
# Test vector from RFC 7539, sec 2.8.2
plaintext1 = b"Ladies and Gentlemen of the class "
plaintext2 = b"of '99: If I could offer you only one"
plaintext3 = b" tip for the future, sunscreen would be it."
nonce = bytes.fromhex("070000004041424344454647")
key = bytes.fromhex("808182838485868788898a8b8c8d8e8f909192939495969798999a9b9c9d9e9f")

# Encryption
ccEnc = ChaCha20Poly1305(True, key, nonce)
ccEnc.updateAAD(bytes.fromhex('50515253c0c1c2c3c4c5c6c7'))
ct1 = ccEnc.update(plaintext1)
ct2 = ccEnc.update(plaintext2)
ct3 = ccEnc.update(plaintext3)
tag = ccEnc.calculate_tag()

print("Ciphertext:\n%s\n" % (ct1 + ct2 + ct3).hex())
print("Tag:\n%s\n" % tag.hex())

# Decryption
ccDec = ChaCha20Poly1305(False, key, nonce)
ccDec.updateAAD(bytes.fromhex('50515253c0c1c2c3c4c5c6c7'))
dt1 = ccDec.update(ct1)
dt2 = ccDec.update(ct2)
dt3 = ccDec.update(ct3)
ccDec.verify_tag(tag)

print("Decrypted:\n%s\n" % (dt1 + dt2 + dt3))
```

Note: **It's of course important not to trust the decrypted data until it has been successfully authenticated!** Just like the *PyCryptodome* implementation, the construct tempts to work with unauthenticated (and possibly corrupted) data. This problem has already been pointed out in detail in the comments and more reliable alternatives have also been suggested (see also the linked post in the other answer).

Comment: In the `updateAAD` method, did you mean `self._aadLength += len(aad)`?

Comment: I have assumed here that only one call of `updateAAD` takes place. To avoid misunderstandings, I have added this information as comment in the code. If several `updateAAD` calls are to be executed, further adjustments are necessary (such as updating the length). Also the padding of the AAD must then be implemented in such a way that it is performed after the last `updateAAD` and before the first `update`.

Answer (score 0):

> It simply takes a piece of data, encrypts it and returns the ciphertext with appended MAC. And that is not what I want.

I think this is what you really want. This is how the popular AE (and AEAD) works.

BTW, have you seen [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55490/stream-cipher-with-an-additional-integrity-stream)?

Comment: But [`Pycryptodome-ChaCha20Ploy1305`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/chacha20_poly1305.html#chacha20-poly1305-and-xchacha20-poly1305) supports encrypting long messages, and is quite different from the `pyca/cryptography`'s design.